# Get generic interface class object

Tags: java

How to get class object of a generic interface?
For example, Boolean.class, Date.class.
But List<Boolean>.class doesn't seem to be syntax-valid.

Comment: Whatever you're doing here is almost certainly wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write `List.class`. `List<Boolean>` is not of a different type, at runtime. The generic type only exists at compile time. So this imaginary `List<Boolean>.class` would not exist to be used in your program.

There is no way to programmatically access the generic type, since it is not present in the byte code. It is only to help the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Due to [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure), your `List<Boolean>` will be converted to a simple raw `List` at runtime, thus, your best bet is to use `List.class`.